# some built in procedures missing

Tags: neo4j, failed-installation

build neo4j 3.3.5 on Debian9

1) community with installer 
2) Enterprise Edition with installer
3) stand alone from github

and i can´t get the complete Built-in procedures on every install. Most of all is missing dbms.security*.

CALL dbms.procedures() shows only less. if calling dbms.security.listUsers() the error is: "Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound"

somebody with an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: this procedure is listed in "User management for Community Edition",but not if i call "CALL dbms.procedures()"

Comment: "doesn´t work"  means an error...

Comment: the install process: enterprise and community via Debian installer and the stand alone via github -> local directory and ./bin/neo4j start

Comment: do you have some errors on the `debug.log` at the startup of Neo4j ?

Comment: FYI, security procedure are part of the `neo4j-security-3.X.X.jar`. Can you check that you have it inside the neo4j's lib folder (and check the rights) ?

Comment: DEBUG: no, there are no errors. ->

the "neo4j-security-3.3.5.jar" is on its place on neo4j-community-3.3.5/lib.

Comment: the "neo4j-security-3.3.5.jar" is on its place on neo4j-community-3.3.5/lib.
if i call for the dbms.procedures() i doesn´t get the procedures shown in the Community-Listing for Neo4j Community. For example: "call dbms.security.listUsers()" results an error: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound: There is no procedure with the name `dbms.security.listUsers`.

The same with "dbms.security.showCurrentUser()"

Comment: Ok ... and you are only getting this on all three installations (apt-get ee, apt-get ce and what I assume is a manual build) or just on the manual build one ?

Answer (score 0):

The community edition does not have user/role management and thus does not have those procedures activated. It is as simple as that. The same applies for example if you run the enterprise edition in single instance mode ... you will not see the cluster related procedures (even though they may be there in the installed product).

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: thank you, but the "CALL dbms.showCurrentUser()" shows an error. And this procedure should be a built-in one.